# How to design a data model to be usable across different application frameworks?

Tags: wpf, windows-services, software-design, separation-of-concerns

I have a WPF GUI application based on MVVM design and data binding. Now, I want to reuse the core code (i.e. the data model) in a Windows service, or a console UI app, or a WinForms app.

Is such a design reasonable? If yes, what are the pitfalls?
Or should I make a standalone data model instead, and interface WPF via wrappers?

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, I should have been more precise. Let me clarify: I don't doubt the very modularity thing =) My concern boils down to having my current DataModel implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, use `DispatcherTimers`, etc. -- all that *non-GUI but still WPF stuff*. The model's business logic is based on it.

Is *this* (non-GUI WPF) design acceptable for reuse in the aforementioned cases, or should I abstract further, until no references to WPF would be required at all?

Comment: As [your question is somewhat subjective](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), don't be surprised if it either gets deleted by the community, or does not get answered. You *could* always try implementing a model in two frameworks and see if it works... I see no reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: @Sheridan Rubbish, sir! there are achievable, documented and measurable advantages to separating domain code from presentation code.

Comment: @Gusdor, please explain to me exactly what did I say that was 'Rubbish'? I think that *you* may  have miss-read my comment.

Comment: `DispatcherTimer` doesn't look like a `Business Logic` thing, really. If you really need to use such things from the BL layer, use a decoupling mechanism such as Dependency Injection or Service Locator or the like.

Comment: @Sheridan: I indended to make it more of 'best practices' kind of question, not 'do you like it or not', but probably failed =)

Comment: @HighCore: `DT` is used for protocol processing. It updates the data model, and consequently, the threading issues come into play...

Comment: @vines, I have no opinion either way, but if you read the page I linked to from the Help Center, you'll see both those kinds of questions *should be avoided*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly acceptable and most of the time it is desired!

When you build an MVVM app, it should be in at least 3 formal layers:

- **Presentation** WPF, UI, xaml, behaviors. All that stuff. *Not reusable*
- **Application** The view models and structure that supports your application rules. All that stuff. *Not intended for reuse*
- **Foundation** Database access, business objects. Domain specific algorithms. *Ideally this bit should be reusable anywhere*

The foundation layer is *the clever bit*. This is where the meat in your application sandwich is. It makes perfect sense for this to be totally agnostic of UI technology. WPF, winforms, ASP. It shouldn't even need a UI.

*Edit for question update:*

Removing all references to WPF is hard because sometimes you need a `CollectionViewSource` on your view models for grouping/filtering of results. That is a WPF class.

It is very tempting to view your seperation-of-concerns as 'just dont reference wpf' and that helps but it can make life difficult. Instead, try to be disciplined with the type of behaviors you are putting in. If you find yourself writing 'clever' (domain) code on a view model, shift it to the foundation layer as a business object method or extension. Similarly, if you find yourself implementing `IValueConverter` often, perhaps you should make better use of view models.

One thing is for sure, your foundation layer should never, ever, ever reference WPF.

Comment: I disagree that the application layer is not reusable. ViewModels are UI agnostic and could be reused in any UI technology. Granted, porting WPF-like ViewModels to, say, ASP.Net MVC ain't an easy thing, but my point still stands.

Comment: I certainly agree with the layering thing. Please the the updated question.

Comment: @HighCore I'm sure we've had this conversation before. View models are often tailored to the _mode_ of application you are creating - frequency of updates, when to commit user changes, navigation style, etc. A phone app may not share any of those with a desktop app. "Experts" (the guys who write books about MVVM) recommend against designing for reuse because it adds complexity to your assemblies. I used to design view models for broad scope but it gave me big maintenance headaches.

Comment: @HighCore A concise version: viewmodels are presentation _technology_ agnostic, but _application type_ dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Such a design is very reasonable! You can create a portable C# library for all .NET technologies including WPF, WinRT, ASP MVC, etc which can contain your models. Obviously you'll need to wrap these portable models into a viewmodel anyway, but IPropertyChanged is implemented in all XAML flavors.

Comment: Does it stand for Windows service as well? Having a reference to WPF from a service is my main concern.